# Improve MySQL REGEXP query with any of multiple words MATCHING

Tags: mysql, regex, query-optimization

I noticed that REGEXP query works well with few words but lose a lot of performance by adding more words.

Is there any way to improve a query like this?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE textfield REGEXP ('(word1|word2| ... |word20)');
```

I tried by trying to tweak with FULLTEXT search but that is working worst.

The best performance I had was by chaining "OR LIKE's" and improves very well, but I don't know how to build the query from a list of words(comma separated) with Pure SQL

Comment: In MySQL, any query like this will have to do a full table scan, and so is doomed to slowness. Postgres has trigram indexes, which do a much better job of `LIKE '%word%'` filtering. FULLTEXT also does better, but you say it is slow.

Comment: Show us the actual SELECT ... MATCH ... AGAINST and SHOW CREATE TABLE.  And drop the identical question in StackExchange.  StackOverflow is a better place for optimizing queries.